# Is there any reason for "co_" wording in new C++ standard?

Tags: c++, coroutine

Reasons for this syntax:

- [no one at cppcon knows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw&t=2940s)

Reasons against it:

- It all worked perfectly with out `co_` [see here](https://youtu.be/_fu0gx-xseY) and was expected (e.g. taught in universities)
- Complicated code (the more chars we type the more errors we get)
- Can be harder to understand and move from other languages (where `return` and await [wording is used](https://youtu.be/_fu0gx-xseY?t=2393))

So why we `co_` wording is there while `co_`less sintax was compiler supported in 2015?

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious answer (namely, "await" and "yield" are identifiers in common usage, so turning them into keywords would break tons of code)? "*the more chars we type the more errors we get*" ... That's a pretty absurd argument against the "co_" prefix.

Comment: @NicolBolas: please present us with a proof of `obvious answer` in real life use (popular library\opensource software), where `await` or `yield` are used for other means (or at least used)!

Comment: I do not agree with the close votes for "primarily opinion based", can the ones voting on that please explain? As I see the question it seeks the reason from the standard committee why the wording in the standard was as written. There must be an actual reason behind it, even if that reason is based primarily on opinion.

Comment: I don't know the reason but I'm willing to say that `the more chars we type the more errors we get` is definitely not correct in a variety of cases. Many many times typing out a few more characters makes code much more readable 1, 2, 5 years down the line.

Comment: thread::yield() would be an obvious real-life example.  Microsoft played around with this and make yield context-sensitive, an identifier when followed by `(`, a keyword otherwise (N4402, page 16).  Didn't get loved, not surprising.

Comment: @MarkB: Is `co_` really clear? They could at least make overloads for `return`, do `coroutine::return` and allow to apply `using` to get read of `coroutine`...

Comment: @DuckQueen `return` is a keyword and can't be overloaded. And while there might be a better approach than `co_`, `await` and `yield` are common single words so it's absolutely likely that turning them into keywords will break existing code.

Comment: _"Complicated code (the more chars we type the more errors we get)"_ Really? "Complicated"? If the phrase `co_` is "complicated" to you you're in the wrong job my friend

Comment: Having not followed C++17 (C++20?) I actually have no idea what you're talking about. Perhaps you could add some context to your question?

Comment: @TommyAndersen The reason I voted as POB is this basically boils down to why did the standard committee do X.  Baring some document somewhere on the internet being found it is all conjecture until one of the members answers here which is very unlikely.

Comment: @MarkB: do you have any real code base in mind, any codebase in current C++11/98 that would use `yield` ant like @HansPassant proposed (when it is just a member of a type or namespace)?

Comment: @NathanOliver a lot of the discussion from the standard committee can actually be found, historically there are many peculiar reasons behind decisions in the standard, such as the reason why a static variable is initialized, while an automatic variable is not. I find these reasons educational and helping one in understanding the language, for that reason I find that it is not primarily opinion based. If it was there would be no actual real reason to present. :)

Comment: @TommyAndersen: "*a lot of the discussion from the standard committee can actually be found*" And a lot cannot. Should we deem such questions opinion-based or not, based on whether such information publicly exists? The P0057 papers are pure wording, without any explanations for why decisions were made. And none of the meeting minutes or trip reports explain why decisions about them were made. The fact is, even the premise of the question is false, since no *formal* wording (versions of P0057) used the keywords `await` and `yield`. It used placeholders.

Comment: @NicolBolas I do not think that a question can be marked invalid if no answers exist. I certainly do not think that the question is primarily opinion based, whether the design decision in question is a result of opinion based decisions is not the same as this question being opinion based. So I do not agree on the vote, I would however understand a vote for off-topic, which is even what you argue for with the premise of the question being wrong, but then that should have been where the votes were placed. We can also agree to disagree :)

Comment: If one looks at the discussion above it gets clear that there is an answer and community is actively arguing around it. So please reopen this question and post the answer.